# Issue after moving the RequestSpecification code under @BeforeClass

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured

Below code works fine for me:

```
    @Test (priority=1, dependsOnMethods = {"checkIfAllServicesAreUp"})
    public void verifyCreateUser() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "someValidURI";
        RestAssured.basePath = "userservice/user/";
        RequestSpecification spec = new RequestSpecBuilder().setContentType(ContentType.JSON).log(LogDetail.METHOD).build();
        response = RestAssured.given().spec(spec).headers("source","APP").body("{ }").when().post("");
    }
```

But when I move the `RequestSpecification` related code under `@BeforeClass` in below manner:

```
    private RequestSpecification spec;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setSpec() {
        spec = new RequestSpecBuilder().setContentType(ContentType.JSON).log(LogDetail.METHOD).build();
    }

    @Test (priority=1, dependsOnMethods = {"checkIfAllServicesAreUp"})
    public void verifyCreateUser() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "someValidURI";
        RestAssured.basePath = "userservice/user/";
        response = RestAssured.given().spec(spec).headers("source","APP").body("{ }").when().post("");
    }
```

My API test returns error code 405 (Method not allowed).

It seems `spec` is overriding the `RestAssured.basePath` assignment inside my test method `verifyCreateUser` since I'm not setting the same in `spec` explicitly, and the POST call is getting hit at `someValidURI` instead of `someValidURI+/userservice/user`, and hence the 405 error code. I do not want to set the `basePath` in `spec` since it would be different for each of my test methods. Please help find an elegant solution here.

Comment: have you tried annotating setSpec to @BeforeTest instead of @BeforeClass?

Comment: @ManuelS. I've tried annotating the setSpec method to a `@BeforeTest` as well as `@BeforeMethod`, but no luck.

Comment: If you remove (priority=1, dependsOnMethods = {"checkIfAllServicesAreUp"}) from Test, does it then work? I've had some issues in the past, where I had to annotate the '@BeforeClass' with the same parameters as the '@Test'

Comment: Even with that, no luck. Nevertheless, I think I've figured out the cause.  I believe it's happening since the `spec` is overriding the `basePath` in the test to "" since I haven't set that explicitly in the `spec`. I'll check the code tomorrow and update.

Comment: @ManuelS. I've added my findings in the original post. Trying to find an elegant solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified my code as mentioned below and it's working fine now:

```
@Test (priority=1, dependsOnMethods = {"checkIfAllServicesAreUp"})
public void verifyCreateUser() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "someValidURI";
    RequestSpecification spec = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBasePath("userservice/user/").setContentType(ContentType.JSON).log(LogDetail.METHOD).build();
    response = RestAssured.given().spec(spec).headers("source","APP").body("{ }").when().post("");
}
```

Apparently, the way I was configuring the `basePath` per test was incorrect earlier. I now do it within `spec`.

Hope this helps someone in future.